# Does Unity's free version come with full source code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am thinking of using Unity's free version. Does anyone know if it comes with full source code?

Also, what are the licenses like (how flexible compare to Torque engine.)

Comment: Looks like there is an [unofficial code repository using ILSpy-decompiled code](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unity does not comes with full source.  You can request a source license, but the price is negotiated I believe.  See bottom of page - https://store.unity3d.com/shop/

I have used both Unity and Torque and find Unity to be much more accessible.  While Torque comes with full source, the design, resources, and overall support is lacking with GarageGames.  My advice is to choose Unity3D.

Answer (score 7):

You should find this blog post highly useful:
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2009/03/20/why-you-probably-dont-need-a-source-code-license/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, answers should contain relevant information in their body.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's worth adding that now [Unity Indie is free](http://unity3d.com/#freeunity)! It does not come with the source code. The licence comparison page is [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Unity license chart](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, answers should contain relevant information in their body.